# R: overlay a line on a raster stack/brick, and get profile of cell values along the line

Tags: raster, r

I've combed through R's raster functions and vignettes and can't seem to get this working.

I want to specify a line/vector across a raster stack (a DEM and possibly related variables), and get a profile of values for the cells which the line intersects. I've been able to do something similar using `mask` with a polygon.

EDIT: Thanks to scw, I have developed the following solution.

```
# I have a stack of environmental rasters in this format
new_r <- raster(ncol=615, nrow=626, xmn=-156.2, xmx=-154.8, ymn=18.89, ymx=20.30)
res(new_r) <- 0.00225
projection(new_r) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
values(new_r) <- outer(seq_len(nrow(new_r)), seq_len(ncol(new_r)), "+")
stackdata <- stack(new_r, sqrt(new_r))

# I designate two transect lines by long/lat
cds1 <- rbind(c(-156, 19), c(-155.5, 20.2))
cds2 <- rbind(c(-155, 20.2), c(-155, 19.2))
transects <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cds1)), ID = "one"), 
                               Lines(list(Line(cds2)), ID = "two")))

# plot the lines to confirm placement
plot(new_r)
plot(transects, add = TRUE)

# and return a list whose length is equal to the number of line segments,
# and each list element is a matrix with a column for each raster layer
e <- extract(stackdata, transects)
```

Comment: `extract` function prints an annoying long string of `1`s while it runs. This can be hidden with `invisible(capture.output(e <- extract(...)))`, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `extract` should do the trick, but you may need to update to the version of raster [on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) first. To use it, pull in the geometries you're interested in into SpatialLines objects like so:

```
require raster
require rgdal

r <- raster('dem.tif')
lines <- readOGR(dsn='lines.shp', layer='lines')

elevations <- extract(r, lines)
```

This works well for most analysis, but isn't fast enough if you're performing very large sets of data (I have an OGR/GDAL implementation I can post somewhere if it'd be useful).

Comment: +1.  But approximately how large is "very large"?  And how fast is "fast enough"?

Comment: Thanks, I have done it slightly different but you put me on the right track. This takes under a minute with my sample data, so is "fast enough." My related question is at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/r-download-a-large-dem-change-projection-and-adjust-to-smaller-scale

Comment: @whuber: I had 7.1M lines (a distance matrix between geometries), and the raster extract function without optimization was doing about 8 lines/sec or 42k points/sec or 10 days for the dataset. The OGR/GDAL version computed the entire dataset in about 4.5hrs.

Comment: @whuber: raster is certainly an evolving package, a coworker found an area where a small optimization to the package generated a 100x speed increase.

Comment: My faster Python based version, for anyone needing to do many extraction operations: https://github.com/scw/topographic-distance/blob/master/lines.py

Comment: @scw would it be possible to share the OGR/GDAL implementation somewhere? I would like to extract raster values per line feature and cannot find a corresponding module. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If speed is an issue, consider using RSAGA with the profiles from lines module. http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/7.2.0/ta_profiles_4.html

Comment: broken link, please update.