# How can I project very large rasters with terra, raster or stars packages in r?

Tags: raster, r, arcgis-pro, terra, stars

I am trying to project a very large raster (about 7GB each) from NAD 1983 UTM Zone 16N to Wisconsin Transverse Mercator (ESPG:3071) and neither the terra nor the raster package seem to work. Terra gives a memory error of "Error: [project] cannot create dataset from source
In addition: Warning message:
memdataset.cpp, 1246: cannot allocate 1x1694928277512 bytes (GDAL error 2) " when I run this:

```
urb_tree_2020 <- terra::rast("local_drive_very_large_raster.tif")
urb_tree_2020_wtm <- terra::project(urb_tree_2020, 
                             "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-90 +k=0.9996 +x_0=520000 +y_0=-4480000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs",
                             res = 1,
                             method = "near")
```

It runs with the raster package, but ran for 4 days without creating an object.

```
urb_tree_2020 <- raster::raster("local_drive_very_large_raster.tif")
urb_tree_2020_wtm <- raster::projectRaster(urb_tree_2020, 
                             "EPSG:3071", 
                              method = "near")
```

And running it with stars, I get the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1578.5 Gb."

```
urb_tree_2020 <- stars::read_stars("local_drive_very_large_raster.tif")
urb_tree_2020_wtm <- stars::st_warp(urb_tree_2020,
                                    crs = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-90 +k=0.9996 +x_0=520000 +y_0=-4480000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs",
                                    method = "near",
                                    use_gdal = TRUE)
```

I did manage to get this to work using ArcGIS Pro, but it took 3 days to run.

Are the files just too big to run locally in R? If so, this would be surprising because terra rocked when doing all sorts of raster math and reclassification on the antecedent datasets, which were all 7-10gb. Is projecting just that much more complex?

Details: the current dataset is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 16N, ESPG 26916 1m resolution over Wisconsin. 434853 columns, 487213 rows, with an origin at 39550, 4703792. I am attempting to project it to Wisconsin transverse Mercator, ESPG 3071 at 1m resolution.

Comment: Have you tried this solution - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383680/memory-issues-projecting-a-large-raster-mosaic-of-usgs-dems-in-r

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the basic info about your raster - size, extent, resolution,CRS etc. "Very large" isn't really sufficient information to work on...